# Codes suddenly changes and result to errors

Tags: android-studio

I'm just a beginner in android studio and I noticed something weird while programming. Some codes suddenly changes which results to error. Then I have to reprogram it again. This is the 4th time. Please help. thank you in advance.[image: :)]

Comment: What is the error, exactly? don't give images, copy your code instead!

Comment: Clean project..